# Strange output when expanding a RLE string in C

Tags: c, memory

I have been banging my head about this for days. I have to make a program for University that used Run Length Encoding to either compress or decompress an ASCII art file depending on the first character in the string a 'C' or an 'E'. The compression part is working like a charm. BUT the expansion is just ever so slightly off on 2/60 lines. And I just cannot figure out why. Belo is the code for my expand() function and main() I didn't include my compress() because it is working correctly

I have tried to check for memory leaks/ buffer overflows but to no avail, As far as I know Im freeing memory correctly. and making sure that strings from a new line are not being read as the previous.

ASCII Art input:
(E for expansion)

```
E
   20###05
   12###07   06#**#!!###03
   11#**#!!!04##   03#***04#!!!04#
   10#***04###03!!!03#  #***05#!!!04#
   10#***07#!!!03# #***06#!!!04#
   10#***09#!###03!*!*!*#!!!05#   08--
   10#!*!*!*!*!*!#!###0A!!!04#   06/_
   10###0B!##!!!0A#!!!03#   05//__
   0D###03!!!0B#!!!0D#!!!03###04///03  \
   03\   07##!#!!!0B#!!!0F#!!!07#
   03_\   04##!!#!!!0B#!!!0B###06!!!07*#
   04\\  ##!!#!!!0C#!!!04###07   05#!!!06***03#
  ___03\\#!!!03###13***05   07#...03!!***05#
 /   03\#!!!03.#   07***05 #   05***03   08#...04***07#
   05#*...04#   08***03   03#   0E#...07***05#
   04#**...05##   0A***05   0A##...08!!***04#
   04#!...08##   07***07###09...06#...03!!!05*#
   03#!...0B###07.***05...0F#.#..!!!04**#
  #*...05##...0D#..#...0F#...03#.!!***04#
  #*...04#.#...0C#...04#...0C##...06!***05#
  #*...07##...07###03...06###03...08#...07!!!03***04#
  #*...09###07...06!!...04###08...07!!!05***03#
   03#!!!03...11!!!08...0D!!!03***07#
   04#!!!04...0C!!!1B***06#
   05#***07!!!1C***03!!!04***05#
   06#***06!!!19***08!!***04#
   07##***05!!!15#***0D###03
   09##***04!!!15###03***06###04
   0B###04!!!18###06!#
   0F#!!!1E*#
   0F#!!!1D***03##
   0E#!!!1D***06#
   0D#!!!1D***07#
   0C#!!!20***05#
   0B#!!!23**#
   0A#!!!27##
   09#!!!29*##
   08#!!!2B***03#
   08#!!!21###04!!!06***04##
   07#!!!1F###03***04##!!!04***06##
   07#!!!1D##**!!***05#!!!03***08#
   07#!!!08#!!!0B#!!!07#***03!!!04***03!!!04***0A#
   06#!!!0A#!!!09#!!!07#***04!!!05*!!!0A***05#
   06#!!!0B#!!!07#!!!07#*!!***03!!!11***03#
   06#!!!0C#!!!06#!!!06#*!!!05*!!!0F***05#
   06#!!!0C#!!!06#!!!05#***03!!!11***08#
   05#!!!0D#!!!06#!!!05#***04!!!0E***0A#
   05#!!!0D#!!!06#!!!05#***05!!!0E***09#
   05#!!!0D#!!!06#!!!05#***03!!!11***08##
   04##!!!0D#!!!06#!!!05#*!!!15***05#!*##
   03#!#!!!08###06!!!06#!!!05#**!!!0A###09!!!04*#!!**##
  #!#!#!!!06#!!!0C#!!!05#***03!!!05###04***06!!!03###07!!**#
 #!#!!##!!!04#!!!0B###0C*!!!03#***08!!!0F**#
 #!#!!#!#!!#!!!03#!!!07#!!!0F#***0B!!!0F#
 #!#!!!03#!#!#!!#!!!07#!!!04#!!!04#!!!05#***0A!!!0F**#
 #!!#!!!03#!##!!#!!!06#!!!04#!!!04#!!!06#***0C!!!0A***04#
  ###09 ###0A!!!04#!!!04#!!!06#***0A!!!0C***03#
   16###11***0C!!!0A**#
   26#***0A!!!05###09
   27###0F
```

Expected output ASCII art:

```
                                #####
                  #######      #**#!!###
                 #**#!!!!##   #****#!!!!#
                #****###!!!#  #*****#!!!!#
                #*******#!!!# #******#!!!!#
                #*********#!###!*!*!*#!!!!!#        --
                #!*!*!*!*!*!#!##########!!!!#      /_
                ###########!##!!!!!!!!!!#!!!#     //__
             ###!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!####///  \
   \       ##!#!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!#
   _\    ##!!#!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!!!!!######!!!!!!!*#
    \\  ##!!#!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!#######     #!!!!!!***#
  ___\\#!!!###################*****       #...!!*****#
 /   \#!!!.#       ***** #     ***        #....*******#
     #*....#        ***   #              #.......*****#
    #**.....##          *****          ##........!!****#
    #!........##       *******#########......#...!!!!!*#
   #!...........#######.*****...............#.#..!!!!**#
  #*.....##.............#..#...............#...#.!!****#
  #*....#.#............#....#............##......!*****#
  #*.......##.......###......###........#.......!!!****#
  #*.........#######......!!....########.......!!!!!***#
   #!!!.................!!!!!!!!.............!!!*******#
    #!!!!............!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!******#
     #*******!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!***!!!!*****#
      #******!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!********!!****#
       ##*****!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#*************###
         ##****!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!###******####
           ####!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!######!#
               #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*#
               #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!***##
              #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!******#
             #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*******#
            #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*****#
           #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**#
          #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!##
         #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*##
        #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!***#
        #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!####!!!!!!****##
       #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!###****##!!!!******##
       #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!##**!!*****#!!!********#
       #!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!#***!!!!***!!!!**********#
      #!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!#****!!!!!*!!!!!!!!!!*****#
      #!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!#*!!***!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!***#
      #!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!#!!!!!!#*!!!!!*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*****#
      #!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!#!!!!!#***!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!********#
     #!!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!#!!!!!#****!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**********#
     #!!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!#!!!!!#*****!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*********#
     #!!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!#!!!!!#***!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!********##
    ##!!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!#!!!!!#*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*****#!*##
   #!#!!!!!!!!######!!!!!!#!!!!!#**!!!!!!!!!!#########!!!!*#!!**##
  #!#!#!!!!!!#!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!#***!!!!!####******!!!#######!!**#
 #!#!!##!!!!#!!!!!!!!!!!############*!!!#********!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**#
 #!#!!#!#!!#!!!#!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#***********!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#
 #!#!!!#!#!#!!#!!!!!!!#!!!!#!!!!#!!!!!#**********!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**#
 #!!#!!!#!##!!#!!!!!!#!!!!#!!!!#!!!!!!#************!!!!!!!!!!****#
  ######### ##########!!!!#!!!!#!!!!!!#**********!!!!!!!!!!!!***#
                      #################************!!!!!!!!!!**#
                                      #**********!!!!!#########
                                       ###############
```

Actual output(Difference is surrounded by ((eg))

```
       (((###############¶ ¶¶¶¶¶¶                         #####)))
                  #######      #**#!!###
                 #**#!!!!##   #****#!!!!#
                #****###!!!#  #*****#!!!!#
                #*******#!!!# #******#!!!!#
                #*********#!###!*!*!*#!!!!!#        --
                #!*!*!*!*!*!#!##########!!!!#      /_
                ###########!##!!!!!!!!!!#!!!#     //__
             ###!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!####///  \
   \       ##!#!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!#
   _\    ##!!#!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!!!!!######!!!!!!!*#
    \\  ##!!#!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!#######     #!!!!!!***#
  ___\\#!!!###################*****       #...!!*****#
 /   \#!!!.#       ***** #     ***        #....*******#
     #*....#        ***   #              #.......*****#
    #**.....##          *****          ##........!!****#
    #!........##       *******#########......#...!!!!!*#
   #!...........#######.*****...............#.#..!!!!**#
  #*.....##.............#..#...............#...#.!!****#
  #*....#.#............#....#............##......!*****#
  #*.......##.......###......###........#.......!!!****#
  #*.........#######......!!....########.......!!!!!***#
   #!!!.................!!!!!!!!.............!!!*******#
    #!!!!............!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!******#
     #*******!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!***!!!!*****#
      #******!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!********!!****#
       ##*****!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#*************###
         ##****!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!###******####
           ####!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!######!#
               #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*#
               #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!***##
              #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!******#
             #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*******#
            #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*****#
           #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**#
          #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!##
         #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*##
        #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!***#
        #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!####!!!!!!****##
       #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!###****##!!!!******##
       #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!##**!!*****#!!!********#
       #!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!#***!!!!***!!!!**********#
      #!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!#****!!!!!*!!!!!!!!!!*****#
      #!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!#*!!***!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!***#
      #!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!#!!!!!!#*!!!!!*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*****#
      #!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!#!!!!!#***!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!********#
     #!!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!#!!!!!#****!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**********#
     #!!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!#!!!!!#*****!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*********#
     #!!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!#!!!!!#***!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!********##
    ##!!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!!#!!!!!#*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*****#!*##
   #!#!!!!!!!!######!!!!!!#!!!!!#**!!!!!!!!!!#########!!!!*#!!**##
((!!!!***#)) #!#!#!!!!!!#!!!!!!!!!!!!#!!!!!#***!!!!!####******!!!#######!!**#
 #!#!!##!!!!#!!!!!!!!!!!############*!!!#********!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**#
 #!#!!#!#!!#!!!#!!!!!!!#!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#***********!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#
 #!#!!!#!#!#!!#!!!!!!!#!!!!#!!!!#!!!!!#**********!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**#
 #!!#!!!#!##!!#!!!!!!#!!!!#!!!!#!!!!!!#************!!!!!!!!!!****#
  ######### ##########!!!!#!!!!#!!!!!!#**********!!!!!!!!!!!!***#
                      #################************!!!!!!!!!!**#
                                      #**********!!!!!#########
                                       ###############((¶))
```

Comment: Start with something *much* smaller that still replicates the problem. Then use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values to see what really happens.

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and help others understand your code and problem.

Comment: I don't get the corruption at the end, but when you debug it, take a look at the initial value of the char array / string `output`. Think about how you got that space for the string and any assumptions you may have made about the lump of memory, the fact that you're using `strncat()` (which expects to be adding to a properly null-terminated string), and hopefully the penny will drop. Also, be warned, you allocate twice the size of the input - but what about repeated characters? Get enough of them and even twice as big may not be enough - buffer overrun...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These statements leads to *undefined behavior*:

```
strncat(output, &currentChar, 1);
```

The `strncat` function requires that the destination is a proper null-terminated string.

`output` is not a null-terminated string, because `malloc` does not initialize the memory it allocates. Its contents will be *indeterminate*.  Use `calloc` to "clear" the allocated memory (set all bytes to zero).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the allocation

```c
char *output = (char *)malloc(2 * strlen(input) + 1);
```

is wrong. For example, a short input

```
###20
```

can be expanded into a long output (more than double of the input length)

```
################################
```

You have to allocate enough space. For example:

```c
char *output = malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN + 1);
```

Also note that casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Secondly, you have to initialize the allocated buffer before using [`strncat()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncat.3p.html).
Otherwise, *undefined behavior* will be invoked by using values in buffer allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized.
You can do this by adding

```c
output[0] = '\0';
```

before the `for` loop in the function `expand`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two fine answers that address two _off-the-top issues in the OP's code.
This response seeks to address a fundamental issue that may have pre-empted the OP's problem; that being *design*.

A finite buffer is not the appropriate solution to this problem.
For the defined input of "ASCII Art", simple *Run Length Encoding* should be written as a filter for a stream of characters
(analogous to a ribosome transcribing a strand of DNA to mRNA.)

Further, using 2 hexadecimal characters to represent 1-255 repetitions is not appropriate when *most* repetitions in ASCII Art files will be far fewer than that.
The objective is to quickly and losslessly reduce the number of bytes needed to represent an "image."

To this end, the following *simpler* code is offered as a learning example.

The scheme below:

- "buffers" only two characters at a time, fixing the issue of "required buffer size"
- uses the buffers provided by the standard i/o library functions for efficiency
- uses easily convertible 'A'-'Z' to represent 1-26 repetitions of a character
- and - its best feature - it is simple!

The compressed version is always two bytes: the ASCII character followed by 'A' to 'Z' representing 1 to 26 repetitions of that character.
This is sub-optimal for "high frequency" data exhibiting many alternations of characters in the original version because 1 instance of a source character becomes 2 bytes of "compressed data."
However, it is fast, not requiring function calls or slower translation of the non-contiguous '0'-'9','A'-'F' to 0-15.

27-52 repetitions of a character (eg. '#') are compressed to "#Z#n" (where Z represents the first 26 and 'n' the excess.)
This extends to higher values as needed.

This foundational code could be enhanced to achieve better compression

- replacing 'A' to 'Z' with '0x20' to '0x7E' (SP to '~') to represent up to 63 repetitions in only two printable characters
- or, by recognising non-uppercase "counts" as indicating a run of high-frequency alterations of two "plain text" characters. (This is left as an exercise for the reader.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void out( int ch, int cnt ) {
    for( ; cnt > 0; cnt -= 26 )
        printf( "%c%c", ch, 'A' - 1 + (cnt > 26 ? 26 : cnt) );
}

int main( int ac, char *av[] ) {
    if( ac != 2 ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s c|e < infile > outfile\n", av[0] );
        return 1;
    }
    int ch, chPrev = '\n', cnt = 0;

    if( av[1][0] == 'c' ) { // compress
        while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF )
            if( ch == '\n' ) {
                out( chPrev, cnt ); // buffered reps of last char
                putchar( chPrev = ch ); // newline
                cnt = 0; // reset
            } else if( ch == chPrev ) {
                cnt++; // tabulate repetitions
            } else {
                if( cnt ) // don't output for very first char of source
                    out( chPrev, cnt );
                chPrev = ch;
                cnt = 1;
            }
        out( chPrev, cnt ); // flush last bufferload (if needed)
    }

    if( av[1][0] == 'e' ) // expand
        while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF ) // first is the character
            if( ch == '\n' )
                putchar( ch ); // self evident
            else {
                cnt = getchar(); // then is the rep count as 'A' to 'Z' (1-26)
                // needs error detection/handling
                while( cnt-- >= 'A' )
                    putchar( ch ); // output enough repetitions
            }

    return 0;
}
```

This could be made more robust, of course, detecting/handling a source file that is not simple ASCII text (eg. an executable file). Again, left as an exercise.

Finally, although *do-able*, requiring a leading `"C\n"` or `"E\n"` in the data stream is inappropriate.
By convention, command line parameters are used to determine a program's mode of operation.